# Slice or Trim only last characters by certain integer

Tags: javascript, trim, slice

I currently have a long pathname storedin `var imgSrc`

The var is a full web address, e.g `http://mywebsite.co.uk/fyp/login-register/images/avatars/16.png`

I want to grab only the section up until the last slash, so only store `16.png`, and then remove the last `.png`

I tried using a `trim()` function but am not sure how to use the `\` as the delimiter for the trim.

Once I have done this I then need to take the last 3 chars of, so return only the number.

**E.g I need to go from**

```
http://www.myurl.com/images/something/16.png
```

All the way down to:

```
16
```

I think I have that last part covered by `slice`:

```
var srcID = imgSrc.slice(0,3);
```

*web address length is not always the same, so it needs to rely on using `\` instead of using specific hardcoded numbers*

Comment: Wouldn't a regex be a better solution?

Comment: `imgSrc.split('/').pop().split('.').shift()`

Comment: A couple of people mentioned regex, which is a good thing to know, but will the filename always be a number? The examples given so far will only work under that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about splitting by `/`, getting the last part and keeping just the numbers.

```
var srcID = imgSrc.split('/').pop().replace(/\D/g,'');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/rtAR4/1/)

Comment: `document.write` in a jsFiddle? Ooooh they're gonna arrest you ;). For the life of me I couldn't get the fiddle to load. Had to use the full screen link to bring it up.

Comment: @j08691 - I know, warnings everywhere and everything in Fiddle ... "DO NOT USE ..." but it seemed to work for me? I'll change it.

Answer (score 1):

You could 'split' the data:

```
var url = 'http://mywebsite.co.uk/fyp/login-register/images/avatars/16.png';
var arr = url.split('/');
var last = arr.length - 1;
var pic = arr[last].split('.');
//--- image name in now in pic[0
```

]

Answer (score 1):

With a regex:

```
var str ="http://www.myurl.com/images/something/16.png";
var found = str.match(/\d+/);
console.log(found[0]);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cD5eq/)**

Answer (score 0):

The lazy person's string manipulation:

Use the "split" method to break a string up into an array, hinging at whatever character:

```
var urlPieces = imgSrc.split( "/" ),
    lastUrlPiece = urlPieces[ urlPieces.length - 1 ],
    filenamePieces = lastUrlPiece.split( "." ),
    filenameSansExtension = filenamePieces[ 0 ];
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

To get only the last "16.png", you can try with

```
var last = imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var srcID = imgSrc.substr(imgSrc.lastIndexOf('/')).match(/[\w\d]+/)[0];
```

`srcID` will equal `16`.

You'll want to avoid the `slice()` method because it'll only work if the image's filename is two characters long.